# Converting UTF8 to ANSI?

Tags: vb.net, utf-8

I'd like to download a webpage using .Net's `WebClient` class, extract the title (i.e. what's between `<title>` and `</title>`) and save the page to a file.

The problem is, the page is encoded in UTF-8 and the `System.IO.StreamWriter` throws an exception when using a filename with such characters.

I've googled and tried several ways to convert UTF8 to ANSI, to no avail. Does someone have working code for this?

```
'Using WebClient asynchronous downloading
Private Sub AlertStringDownloaded(ByVal sender As Object, 
                                  ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then
        Dim Response As String = CStr(e.Result)

        'Doesn't work               
        Dim resbytes() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Response)
        Response = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, 
                                              Encoding.Default, resbytes))

        Dim title As Regex = New Regex("<title>(.+?) \(", 
                                       RegexOptions.Singleline)
        Dim m As Match
        m = title.Match(Response)
        If m.Success Then
            Dim MyTitle As String = m.Groups(1).Value

            'Illegal characters in path.
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\" & MyTitle & ".txt")
            objWriter.Write(Response)
            objWriter.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Edit: Thanks everyone for the help. It turns out the error was not due to UTF8 but rather a hidden LF character in title section of the page, which is obviously an illegal character in a path.

---

Edit: Here's a simple way to remove some of the illegal characters in a filename/path:

```
Dim MyTitle As String = m.Groups(1).Value
Dim InvalidChars As String = New String(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + New String(Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
For Each c As Char In InvalidChars
    MyTitle = MyTitle.Replace(c.ToString(), "")
Next
```

---

Edit: And here's how to tell WebClient to expect UTF-8:

```
Dim webClient As New WebClient
AddHandler webClient.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf AlertStringDownloaded
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("www.acme.com"))
```

Comment: There is plenty of ASCII characters that cannot be used in a file nime... what is the title exactly?

Comment: Sorry, the characters are fine (although I'd rather have ANSI characters in filenames than UTF8 : "c:\CinÃ©ma Paradiso.txt" isn't user-friendly). I'll find how to remove the hidden, error-inducing LF character

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is related to UTF-8.  I think your regex will include `</title>` if it appears on the same line.  The characters`<>` are invalid in a Windows filename.

If this is not the problem it would be helpful to see some sample input and output values of `MyTitle`.

Comment: Excellent point.  The problem is not encoding.  The problem is illegal characters.  To improve your answer, if you think the RegEx is a problem, I'd recommend giving an example of a better RegEx that would correct the problem.  Also, even if the RegEx is correct, the title may still contain illegal characters.  The `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` method should be used, the get a list of characters that need to be replaced or removed.

Comment: Thanks Steve. You're right, there was a hidden LF character before the actual title :-/ However, I'd rather convert characters from UTF8 to ANSI to make them user-readable.

Comment: Thanks Steven for the tip on "Path.GetInvalidPathChars". There was indeed a hidden, illegal character

Comment: If you want to do anything more than simply removing illegal characters, you are going to have to give an example what what input and output you expect.  Encoding doesn't make any sense in this context.  Encoding is only applicable when you are talking about how to convert from a byte array to a string or vice versa.  In this case you are talking about simply reformatting a string to a string which has nothing to do with encoding.

Comment: Right. I was refering to encoding because I though it was due to the page being in UTF8, but as it turns out the error was due to a LF characters, it's a different issue.